# is there a way to script in Python to change user passwords in Linux? if so, how?

Tags: python, linux, authentication

I'm trying to write some scripts in Python and stumbled upon the need of making something to update the password of a given user in a Linux system...

UPDATE: the objective is to achieve the script to update the password automatically from a given data/algorithm. The important thing is to have no human intervention...

is there a way to achieve that? or should I search through other means?

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `openssl` and `usermod`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess

login = 'username'
password = 'somepassword'

# OpenSSL doesn't support stronger hash functions, mkpasswd is preferred
#p = subprocess.Popen(('openssl', 'passwd', '-1', password), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p = subprocess.Popen(('mkpasswd', '-m', 'sha-512', password), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
shadow_password = p.communicate()[0].strip()

if p.returncode != 0:
    print 'Error creating hash for ' + login

r = subprocess.call(('usermod', '-p', shadow_password, login))

if r != 0:
    print 'Error changing password for ' + login
```

Comment: alright! this almost got it! the thing is that I still need interaction with the script, but indirectly: I need to run it with sudo, asking me for the user password executing the script, even if login variable is the same name as the user running the script. I guess it has to do with usermod, right?

Comment: Yes, it seems so. I don't know if there is a way to get around this. The user that runs `usermod` needs permissions to modify `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/shadow`. You would have to check how `passwd` changes the password without requiring the permissions.

Comment: Thank you very much. Since I pretend to modify automatically the password for a certain user at certain moment, I manage to go around it by using root's crontab (which I can access through sudo crontab -e), and then the script runs as I desire...

Comment: Unfortunately openssl-passwd only supports crypt, md5, and apr1 hashes, and not blowfish or sha1 which are more commonly used nowadays. Also it doesn't check password strength, etc.

Comment: @zbyszek, I guess you're right. It seems that `mkpasswd` is able to generate stronger hashes. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 5):

You can use crypt to do the password hashing instead of using `openssl passwd` (where you are passing the password in plaintext in the command line)

Adapting Juliusz script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess,crypt,random

login = 'username'
password = 'somepassword'

ALPHABET = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
salt = ''.join(random.choice(ALPHABET) for i in range(8))

shadow_password = crypt.crypt(password,'$1$'+salt+'$')

r = subprocess.call(('usermod', '-p', shadow_password, login))

if r != 0:
    print 'Error changing password for ' + login
```

This way, the password is only passed in the command line already hashed (to `usermod`).
I've tested this with ubuntu+python2.6.6+pycrypto2.5.

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to do this again today, and below is my solution. It is fully automatic, and also uses standard system passwd binary, so system policies are respected.

```
#!/usr/bin/python3    

username = 'joe'

# generate passphrase
pw_length = 6
phrase = subprocess.check_output(['pwgen', str(pw_length), '1'])
phrase = phrase.decode('utf-8').strip()

dev_null = open('/dev/null', 'w')
passwd = subprocess.Popen(['sudo', 'passwd', user], stdin=subprocess.PIPE,
                          stdout=dev_null.fileno(),
                          stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
passwd.communicate( ((phrase + '\n')*2).encode('utf-8') )
if passwd.returncode != 0:
    raise OSError('password setting failed')
```

(This generated the password too. Skip the first part if not useful.)

Answer (score 0):

Use `subprocess` to invoke `passwd`.

Comment: thanks for answering, but what I really need is to get it done without human intervention, and as far as I know, passwd requires it...

Comment: Have you tried the options given in the man page? Specifically `--stdin`.

Comment: Consider invoking `usermod` too.

Comment: passwd --stdin is not an option since that parameter is not always present in all distros, or so I've noticed. In my test system, a Debian (and also found the same on Ubuntu, almost obviously), there isn't a --stdin option. I've notived that in CentOS it is present, but the problem remains: not all distros support it...

Comment: I'll take a look at usermod , didn't knew about it, but I tested manually and found that since usermod stores the password "as returned by crypto" (according to man page), the system didn't allow me to login with the usermod-modified password, so I had to su and passwd manually back again... Have to research a little more...